# Remove Rows From UITableView from Previous Selected Section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently I have a UITableView which is expands and collapses with the current code.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section>=0) return YES;
    return NO;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSInteger numberofRows = 0;

    numberofRows = nameArray.count;

    if (numberofRows != 0){
        self.mainTableView.hidden = false;
    }

    return numberofRows;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                cell.accessoryView = [ALCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:ALCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

            }
            else
            {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                cell.accessoryView =  [ALCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:ALCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];

            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Selected Section is %ld and subrow is %ld ",(long)indexPath.section ,(long)indexPath.row);

        }

    }
}
```

This works really well and upon selection of a `UITableViews` section the rows are expanded and populated with the correct data and when the same section is selected the rows are removed and appear collapsed.

However what i want to do is somehow automatically collapse the previous selected section and remove the rows within that previous section when the user selects a new indexpath.section.

I have tried storing the selected section index path to an array removing rows based on this value but I think I'm going about it the wrong way as I get assertion failures.

So my question is as follows :-

**How can i automatically collapse (remove rows) from a uitableviews section upon selection of another section**

Thanks for your help in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have faced this issue when i was writting code for my app and i founded this post that had no any single comment or answer...
You can use this code that i was written for me to colapse previous expanded rows of section when i clicked on other section and expand rows of that section, this code working for me try it...
    `

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section>=0) return YES;

return NO;
}




static NSInteger Value=0;

static NSInteger Value2=0;
static CFIndex indexPre=0;
static NSMutableArray *preArray;
static NSIndexPath *path;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
{
    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.hideButton.hidden=NO;
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        NSUInteger index=[expandedSections firstIndex];

if ([expandedSections indexGreaterThanIndex:index])
        {
            NSLog(@"%lu hhhwww", index);
        }

        NSInteger section = indexPath.section;

      static  NSInteger rows;
        static  NSInteger PreRows;
        NSLog(@"%lu MY INDEXES1",(unsigned long)[expandedSections count]);
        NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        preArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];


         if (currentlyExpanded)
        {
            rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            [expandedSections removeIndex:section];
            Value=0;
            Value2=0;
            cell.hideButton.hidden=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Value==0)
            {

                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                PreRows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                indexPre=indexPath.section;
                Value=1;

            }
            else if (Value==1)
            {
                Value2=1;
                NSLog(@"indexPre == %ld %@ my indexxxxx", indexPre, expandedSections);
                [expandedSections removeIndex:indexPre];
                   NSLog(@"indexPre == %ld %@ my indexxxxx", indexPre, expandedSections);
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                   NSLog(@"indexPre == %ld %@ my indexxxxx", indexPre, expandedSections);
                rows=[self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }


        }

        NSLog(@"%@ MY INDEXES",expandedSections);
        if (Value2==1)
        {
            for (int i=1; i<PreRows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:indexPre];
                [preArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }
            NSLog(@"my arrray %@", preArray);
            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }
            NSLog(@"my arrray  tmparray%@", preArray);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }
        }



        if (currentlyExpanded )
        {


            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                             withRowAnimation:NO];

            cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];


        }
        else if(Value==1)
        {
            if (Value2==1)
            {

                [tableView beginUpdates];

                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:NO];


                cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];

                [tableView endUpdates];
                [tableView beginUpdates];

                [tableView endUpdates];

                indexPre=indexPath.section;
            }
            else
            {

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
            }


        }

    }

}
}
```

`